# RSpec: TypeError When Stubbing Custom Exception

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'd like to test that `Custom::Runner.run` rescues all `StandardErrors` and fires an alert with the exception.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to stub the call to my custom error class, `Custom::Error`, and expecting that `Custom::Alert.error` was received with the double as an argument.

Here's a complete test case to demonstrate the issue:

```
module Custom
  class Error < StandardError
  end
end

module Custom
  class Alert
    def self.error(exception, context = {})
    end
  end
end

module Custom
  class Runner
    def self.run
      request
    rescue => e
      Custom::Alert.error(e, { foo: :bar })
    end

    class << self
      def request
        raise Custom::Error.new('test')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the test:

```
RSpec.describe Custom::Runner do
  describe '.run' do
    let(:custom_error_double) { instance_double(Custom::Error) }

    before do
      # could this be the culprit?
      allow(Custom::Error).to receive(:new)
        .with('test')
        .and_return(custom_error_double, 'test')
    end

    it 'fires a custom alert' do
      expect(Custom::Alert).to receive(:error)
        .with(custom_error_double, foo: :bar)

      described_class.run
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails:

```
Failures:                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                1) Custom::Runner.run fires a custom alert
     Failure/Error: Custom::Alert.error(e, { foo: :bar })                                                                                                    

       #<Custom::Alert (class)> received :error with unexpected arguments                                                                                    
         expected: (#<InstanceDouble(Custom::Error) (anonymous)>, {:foo=>:bar})                                                                              
              got: (#<TypeError: exception class/object expected>, {:foo=>:bar})
       Diff:             
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[#<InstanceDouble(Custom::Error) (anonymous)>, {:foo=>:bar}]
       +[#<TypeError: exception class/object expected>, {:foo=>:bar}]
```

I believe this is because `rescue` requires an exception and I'm returning a double. I've tried raising `.and_raise(custom_error_double)`, but I continue to get the same `TypeError: exception class/object expected`.

There must be something I'm missing here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have it exactly right that the exception vs. the double is the issue. The error specifically is `received :error with unexpected arguments`, and the comparison is that the double does not match the `TypeError`. In this case, the blind `rescue => e` then calls `Custom::Alert.error(e, {foo: :bar})` (which has the `TypeError` as the argument `e`), but in your test the `.with()` is expecting the double.

This will work:

```
RSpec.describe Custom::Runner do
  describe '.run' do
    let(:custom_error) { Custom::Error.new }

    before do
      allow(Custom::Error).to receive(:new).with('test').and_return(custom_error, 'test')
    end

    it 'fires a custom alert' do
      expect(Custom::Alert).to receive(:error).with(custom_error, foo: :bar)

      described_class.run
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the instance double of `Custom::Error` is an `InstanceDouble` object and not an `Exception` object so when you raise the double it causes the `TypeError`.

You could replace the double

```
 let(:custom_error_double) { instance_double(Custom::Error) }
```

with a real `Custom::Error` object

```
 let(:custom_error) { Custom::Error.new }
```

to avoid that.